# comparing numpy arrays with np.allclose()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to Python. I cannot understand the behavior of the following code (I am trying to create a unit test for something):

```
    import numpy as np

    input = np.array([0, 2])
    result = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-input))
    expected_result = np.array([0.5, 0.88079708])

    print(result)
    print(expected_result)

    print(result[1])
    print(expected_result[1])

    is_equal1 = np.array_equal(result, expected_result)
    is_equal2 = np.allclose(result, expected_result, rtol=0.00000000000000000000001)

    print(is_equal1)
    print(is_equal2)
```

This code prints:

```
[0.5        0.88079708]
[0.5        0.88079708]
0.8807970779778823
0.88079708
False
True
```

Why when I print arrays their values are equal, but then I print their last items they are different? If the values are actually different, why `is_equal2` is `True`? If the values are the same, why `is_equal1` is `False`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Why when I print arrays their values are equal, but then I print
> their last items they are different?"

It is because `numpy.ndarray` has a [preset display precision](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) in print.

> "If the values are actually different, why is_equal2 is True?"

According to the docs of [numpy.allclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html), it is comparing element-wise:

absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))

atol is default to be 1e-8, so you need to provide `atol` parameter here instead of `rtol`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. When I add `atol` to the call it works: `is_equal2 = np.allclose(result, expected_result, rtol=0.00000000000000000000001, atol=0)`. I missed the fact that `atol` has a default.